# GUI do Tkinter trava quando executo loop

Tags: python, tkinter

Sou novato em programação e tenho enfrentado algumas dificuldades para executar o código com perfeição.

Escolhi a linguagem python pela sua flexibilidade.

Há algum tempo venho tentando criar um macro com GUI, uso o Tkinter, a janela está do jeito que eu planejei, e os comandos do macro também. Só que quando eu aperto o botão para ligar o macro, a janela trava e para de responder, não consigo clicar no botão novamente para desativar o macro nem nada do tipo, porém percebo que o macro continua em execução perfeitamente.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês para sanar esse travamento na janela do Tkinter.
Aqui está meu código.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ctypes
import time


class Janela:

    def __init__(self, toplevel):

        self.primeira = Frame(toplevel)
        self.primeira.pack()
        self.segunda = Frame(toplevel, pady=10)
        self.segunda.pack()
        self.terceira = Frame(toplevel,)
        self.terceira.pack()

        self.title = Label(self.primeira, text='"Perera" Trainer', font=('Verdana', '13', 'bold'))
        self.title['width'] = 20
        self.title['height'] = 5
        self.title.pack()

        self.nome = Label(self.segunda, text='Hotkey da spell: ', font=('Verdana', '12',), width=13).pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hotkey = Entry(self.segunda, width=2, font=('Verdana', '12', 'bold'))
        self.hotkey.focus_force()
        self.hotkey.pack(side=LEFT)

        Label(self.terceira, text='Ligar Trainer', font=('Arial', '12', 'bold'), height=3,).pack()

        self.botao = Button(self.terceira, font=('Arial', '13', 'bold'), text='ON', bg='gray')
        self.botao.bind("<Button-1>", self.ligar)
        self.botao.pack()

    def ligar(self, event):
        if self.botao['bg'] == 'gray':
            self.botao['bg'] = 'deepskyblue'
        else:
            self.botao['bg'] = 'gray'

        VAR = self.hotkey.get()
        self.hot = int(VAR[1])

        while self.botao['bg'] == 'deepskyblue':
            time.sleep(2)
            if self.hot == 1:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x70, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x70, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 2:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x71, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x71, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 3:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x72, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x72, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 4:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 5:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x74, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x74, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 6:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x75, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x75, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 7:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x76, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x76, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 8:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x77, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x77, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 9:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x78, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x78, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 10:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x79, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x79, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 11:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7A, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7A, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            elif self.hot == 12:
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7B, 0, 0, 0)
                ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7B, 0, 0x0002, 0)

            time.sleep(2)
            ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x8, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x10, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            time.sleep(2)

            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x25, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x25, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x26, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x26, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x27, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x27, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x28, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x28, 0, 0x0002, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)


raiz = Tk()
Janela(raiz)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O teu primeiro problema é o fato de usares `time.sleep`, e o segundo é de usares o `while` loop. Quando usas a função `time.sleep` blocas o mainloop do objecto `Tk` que criastes. O mesmo acontece se tens um loop (que dura algum tempo), ou uma operação que dura bastante. Aqui tens um tutorial se queres saber mais sobre o assunto e quais são algumas possíveis soluções.

> https://github.com/dossan/tkinter/blob/master/other/tutorials/why_your_GUI_freezes.md

Não sem bem o que queres criar (e para quê) com esse programa, mas uma solução seria usar a função [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) de qualquer widget de tkinter (ou melhor qualquer widget tem essa função porque a herda do `Widget` mãe ou pai) Esta função teoricamente não bloca a interface, e permite-te de agendar a execução dum pedaço de código entre um certo tempo que especificas em milissegundos.

Aqui ficas com o teu programa modificado mas usando a função `after`. Se não percebes algo, pergunta.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ctypes
import time


class Janela:

    def __init__(self, toplevel):
        self.primeira = Frame(toplevel)
        self.primeira.pack()
        self.segunda = Frame(toplevel, pady=10)
        self.segunda.pack()
        self.terceira = Frame(toplevel,)
        self.terceira.pack()

        self.title = Label(self.primeira, text='"Perera" Trainer', font=('Verdana', '13', 'bold'))
        self.title['width'] = 20
        self.title['height'] = 5
        self.title.pack()

        self.nome = Label(self.segunda, text='Hotkey da spell: ', font=('Verdana', '12',), width=13).pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hotkey = Entry(self.segunda, width=2, font=('Verdana', '12', 'bold'))
        self.hotkey.focus_force()
        self.hotkey.pack(side=LEFT)

        Label(self.terceira, text='Ligar Trainer', font=('Arial', '12', 'bold'), height=3,).pack()

        self.botao = Button(self.terceira, font=('Arial', '13', 'bold'), text='ON', bg='gray')
        self.botao.bind("<Button-1>", self.ligar)
        self.botao.pack()

    def callback1(self):
        print "callback 1" 

        if self.hot == 1:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x70, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x70, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 2:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x71, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x71, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 3:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x72, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x72, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 4:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 5:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x74, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x74, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 6:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x75, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x75, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 7:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x76, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x76, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 8:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x77, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x77, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 9:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x78, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x78, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 10:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x79, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x79, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 11:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7A, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7A, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        elif self.hot == 12:
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7B, 0, 0, 0)
            ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x7B, 0, 0x0002, 0)

        self.primeira.after(2000, self.callback2)

    def callback2(self):
        print "callback 2"         
        ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x8, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x10, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.primeira.after(2000, self.callback3)

    def callback3(self):
        print "callback 3"           
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x25, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x25, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        self.primeira.after(200, self.callback4)

    def callback4(self):
        print "callback 4"           
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x26, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x26, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        self.primeira.after(200, self.callback5)

    def callback5(self):
        print "callback 5"                   
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x27, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x27, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        self.primeira.after(200, self.callback6)

    def callback6(self):
        print "callback 6"                   
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x28, 0, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x28, 0, 0x0002, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA2, 0, 0x0002, 0)

        if self.botao['bg'] == 'deepskyblue':
            self.primeira.after(200, self.callback1)

    def ligar(self, event):
        if self.botao['bg'] == 'gray':
            self.botao['bg'] = 'deepskyblue'
        else:
            self.botao['bg'] = 'gray'

        VAR = self.hotkey.get()

        self.hot = int(VAR)

        if self.botao['bg'] == 'deepskyblue':
            self.primeira.after(2000, self.callback1)


raiz = Tk()
Janela(raiz)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Nota que não uso mais o `while` loop mais sim um `if` com a possibilidade de agendar outra vez uma chamada a função (ou callback, como se diz em Inglês) `callback1`, a primeira que é chamada com todos os ifs.

Comment: Após algumas edições neste código eu consegui chegar onde queria. Você apenas esqueceu de atribuir [1] depois do VAR, ficaria " self.hot = int(VAR[1]) ". Mesmo assim, muito obrigado.